# if(...) - two equal sides are considered as not equal

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

im new to android and this is my first post in StackOverflow.In short I face a very strange problem :
    in some methods I used if(...) ,and both of the values were equal ,yet it doesn't go through the if .
    Here is an example :

```
String []s=db.getStudentsNames();
        String []t=CopyNames(s);
        String t1,t2;

        t2=Id.getText().toString();
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
        {
            t1=t[i].substring(t[i].indexOf("-")+1).toString();
            Notifications(t[i].substring(t[i].indexOf("-")+1).toString());
            if(t1.toString()==t2.toString())//Problem!
            {
                Notifications("Id already exists for "+t[i].substring(0,t[i].indexOf("-")).toString());
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The variables t1 & t2 are : `t1="123456789"` & `t2="123456789"` , yet it doesn't enter the if like they are not equal.
And there are other places were two equal sides are considered as not equal - in the same java page (activity) like:
`if(add.getText().toString()=="Add Student")` : add refers to a button which has ,by default , a text :"Add Student" 
so how can I solve this problem ?

**when this problem started , I started to see in LogCat:

```
 W/KeyCharacterMap(282): No keyboard for id 0

 W/KeyCharacterMap(282): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

 D/dalvikvm(282): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5438 objects / 256800 bytes in 73ms
```

Comment: Use `t1.toString().equals(t2.toString())`.  What you're doing right now is testing reference pointers in memory.

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `==` to compare Strings in Java. Use `t1.toString().equals(t2.toString())` instead.

Comment: I'll try it..thanks any way

Comment: It works now :) Thanks a lot :) .. I used to program C# and there == works with Strings xD

Comment: im trying but i must wait about 10 minutes ..i'll do it..don't worry

Answer (score 1):

never use `==` on String objects. Use `t1.equals(t2)` instead.